# add user defined object to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unrecognized-selector

I have the following swift class and want to add it in NSMutableArray

```
   class DrawerItem : NSObject{

    var tag : String = ""
    var title : String = ""

    override init () {

        self.tag = "";
        self.title = "";
    }

    init(tag: String) {

        self.tag = tag
    }

    init(title: String) {

        self.title = title
    }
}



self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray new];
[self.dataSource addObject:@"hello"]; //it works 

DrawerItem *item = [DrawerItem new]; // not working
item.tag = @"test";
item.title = @"test";

[self.dataSource addObject:item];
```

and give me the following exception

```
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Khawater.DrawerItem isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: You're mixing Objective-C and Swift here.  Are you using your Swift class in an Objective-C class?

Comment: yes, I have no compilation error, the exception happen after running the application

Comment: You need to post the code that actually causes the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is mixing `NSString` and `DrawerItem` in your dataSource array. At a later point in your code you try to use its items only as Strings and this throws the runtime error.

**Solution nr. 1**
declare the array in swift `var dataSource: [DrawerItem] = []` This will throw a compilation error

**Solution nr. 2**
Use objective-c lightweight generics `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<DrawerItem*> *dataSource;` which will generate compiler warning if there is a mismatch

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way

```
    import Foundation

    class DrawerItem : NSObject{

        var tag : String = ""
        var title : String = ""

        override init () {

            self.tag = "";
            self.title = "";
        }

        init(tag: String) {

            self.tag = tag
        }

        init(title: String) {

            self.title = title
        }
    }

    //creating the first obj
    var drawer: DrawerItem = DrawerItem()

    drawer.tag = "Tag Test"
    drawer.title = "Title Test"

    //creating the second obj
    var drawer1: DrawerItem = DrawerItem()

    drawer1.tag = "Tag Test 1"
    drawer1.title = "Title Test 1"

    var drawerArray:[DrawerItem] = [DrawerItem]()

    //adding to the drawerArray
    drawerArray.append(drawer)
    drawerArray.append(drawer1)


    //testing the array
    for x in drawerArray{
        print(x.title)
    }
```